# Pop if X elements in the past Y seconds?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Sorry, kinda new to RX.NET here... I've been able to do a lot of things in RX, but not the main thing I need to do.

I only want the observable to pop if it has received X elements in the past Y seconds. In other words, at any point in time, when a new element is pushed, look back at the past X elements and see if they all occurred within the past Y seconds.

I can't figure out the "look back and count" part.

It seems like Window would be the right operator, due to is slidability, but perhaps I'm biased in my definition of Window. It feels like the closer function is where I'd do that, but I'm not wizard yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will return the list of `x` elements that fall within your `y` timespan.

```
public static IObservable<IList<T>> GetFullWindows<T>(this IObservable<T> source, int x, TimeSpan y)
{
    return source
        .Publish(_obs => _obs
            .Window(_obs, _ => Observable.Timer(y))
            .SelectMany(window => window.Take(x).ToList())
            .Where(l => l.Count == x)
        );

}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
var obs = Observable.Generate(0, i => i < 20, i => i + 1, i => i, i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((20 - i) * 100));

var b = obs
    .GetFullWindows(4, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.5));

b.Subscribe(l => l.Dump()); //using Linqpad
```

The trick is using `Buffer` or `Window` with the overlapping window feature. `Window` works better here, because you can short-circuit it if you have met the count criteria.